# bash curl/wget with linksys guest network

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I am attempting to use wget/curl to script downloading info from the internet.  I am connected to the "guest" network on my Cisco/Linksys wifi router that requires that I supply a password before I can access the internet.

I tried passing the user/password I use for the admin account to the router, but I still only get the routers login html when I execute something like ...

```
$ wget -O- --user=admin --password=qwerty librivox.org
--2014-11-29 20:05:04--  http://librivox.org/
Resolving librivox.org... 208.70.31.70
Connecting to librivox.org|208.70.31.70|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

    [<=>                                                                                                                              ] 0           --.-K/s              
<html><head><noscript><meta http-equiv=Refresh Content="0; 
URL=http://192.168.3.1:10080/ui/dynamic/guest-login.html"></noscript><script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>function init(_frm) { if (_frm.sent.value == 0) { _frm.sent.value=1; _frm.submit(); } }</script></head>
<body onload=init(auth)>
<form name=auth action='http://192.168.3.1:10080/ui/dynamic/guest-login.html' METHOD=GET>
<input type=hidden name='mac_addr' value='00:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx'>
<input type=hidden name='url' value='http://librivox.org/'>
<input type=hidden name='ip_addr' value='192.168.3.136'>
    [ <=>                                                                                                                             ] 634         --.-K/s   in 0s

2014-11-29 20:05:05 (24.3 MB/s) - written to stdout [634]
```

... how am I suppose to supply that password from a bash script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

looks like you first have to pass mac_addr, url and ip_addr to `http://192.168.3.1:10080/ui/dynamic/guest-login.html` before you are prompted to supply your username/password with something like

```
wget -O- http://192.168.3.1:10080/ui/dynamic/guest-login.html&mac_addr=xxx&url=http://librivox.org&ip_addr=192.168.3.136
```

depending on what is returned you may also pass username/password in that previous step or the next one